# Circular data flow in highlandjs

Tags: node.js, highland.js

I'm just learning highland.js after being inspired by NoFlo.js.  I want to be able to have streams operate recursively.  In this contrived example I will provide a number that get's multiplied by two and we filter results <= 512.  Once the number is multiplied it gets fed back into the system.  The code I have works but if I take out the doto function in the pipeline it doesn't process any numbers.  I suspect that I'm sending the data back into the returnPipe incorrectly.  Is there a better way to pipe data back into a system?  What am I   missing?

```
###
  input>--m--->multiplyBy2>---+
          |                   |
          |                   |
          +---<returnPipe<----+
###

H = require('highland')

input = H([1])
returnPipe = H.pipeline(
  H.doto((v)->console.log(v))
)
H.merge([input,returnPipe])
 .map((v)-> return v * 2)
 .filter((v)-> return v <= 512)
 .pipe(returnPipe)
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't processing any of the numbers?

Comment: As long as the doto call is in there it works. I just wanted to pipe the data without having to put a needless function in there such as doto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation: `doto` spins off a stream while [re-emitting the source stream](http://highlandjs.org/#doto). This means that as far as the pipeline is concerned, there is a function that is still passing the stream through it. If you take `doto` out, the original stream doesn't make it back through return stream on the next iteration.

If you are going to use pipeline, you have to pass it a method that takes a stream and emits a stream. For example, you could replace the `doto` method with something like `H.map((v)=>{console.log(v); return v;})` in the call to `H.pipeline` and since that method consumes a stream *and emits a stream*, it will continue to flow when the stream is passed back into it on `.pipe(returnPipe)`

EDIT: To answer your question, when you declare `let input = H([1])` you are actually creating a stream right there. You can remove any reference to the pipeline and returnPipe and produce the same output with the following code:

```
let input = H([1]);

input.map((v)=> {
  return v * 2;
})
.filter((v)=> {
  if (v <= 512) {
    console.log(v);
  }
  return v <= 512;
})
.pipe(input);
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.  It just intuitively feels like I should be able to pipe the data without any functions whatsoever.  Is there something like a pipeline that will just consume and re-emit?

Comment: See the example in the edit I made. Since the whole idea of a stream is that it consumes and re-emits, and since `H(source)` actually creates a stream object, there is no need to create a separate "pipeline". I believe that the idea of the pipeline is just to provide a convenient wrapper for a series of functions that you want the stream to pass through.

Comment: That would have never occurred to me.  Thanks so much.  Well worth the +50!!

Comment: If you change the map to a flatMap((v)-> return H([v + 1, v+ 2]) then only a single value is printed and the pipe seems to fail.  Debugging highland is pretty rough.

Answer (score 1):

My original intent was to write a recursive file reader in highland.js.  I [posted](https://github.com/caolan/highland/issues/371) to the highland.js github issues list and Victor Vu helped me put this together with a fantastic write-up.

```
H = require('highland')
fs = require('fs')
fsPath = require('path')

###
  directory >---m----------> dirFilesStream >-------------f----> out
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                +-------------< returnPipe <--------------+

  legend: (m)erge  (f)ork

 + directory         has the initial file
 + dirListStream     does a directory listing
 + out               prints out the full path of the file
 + directoryFilter   runs stat and filters on directories
 + returnPipe        the only way i can

###

directory = H(['someDirectory'])
mergePoint = H()
dirFilesStream = mergePoint.merge().flatMap((parentPath) ->
  H.wrapCallback(fs.readdir)(parentPath).sequence().map (path) ->
    fsPath.join parentPath, path
)
out = dirFilesStream
# Create the return pipe without using pipe!
returnPipe = dirFilesStream.observe().flatFilter((path) ->
  H.wrapCallback(fs.stat)(path).map (v) ->
    v.isDirectory()
)
# Connect up the merge point now that we have all of our streams.
mergePoint.write directory
mergePoint.write returnPipe
mergePoint.end()
# Release backpressure.
out.each H.log
```